# Dealing with expected failures in tests

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

**Background:** I have a relatively large Cucumber test suite. The problem is that there are several test cases that will fail due to known bugs that probably won't be fixed for a month or two. This means that whenever myself or someone else needs to run the test suite, we get several failures and then have to spend time digging through the test results and figuring out which ones were expected and which ones are new.

The quick and dirty solution is to simply comment the test cases out. The problem I have with that is that when the bugs are fixed there is no guarantee that the commented out test case will be uncommented.

**Question:** Is there a simple method in Cucumber to separate the expected failures from the unexpected ones?

Comment: Does RSpec have something like this called "pending"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tag them as @wip

The default cucumber call will ignore the @wip scenarios

```
@wip 
Scenario: Something
```

Btw

`rake cucumber:ok  #will run all the scenarions except the @wip ones`

`rake cucumber:wip #will run just the @wip tagged scenarios`

`rake cucumber     #same behavior as rake cucumber:ok`